# What should be the recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem using dynamic programming but getting wrong answer. I think the recurrence i am using is incorrect. What should be the recurrence relation for the problem and what information should the dp state hold? At present, i am using a 2-dimensional array where *dp[i][j]* denotes the maximum number of scoops for rectangle of size *(i x j)*, So answer will be *dp[n - 1][n - 1]*.
-> [Problem Statement](http://www.ahmed-aly.com/p.jsp?ID=222)

My Code:

1) s[n][n] is the grid that is given in the problem.

2) end[i][j].first is 1 if s[i][j] is used in the solution for (i x j) rectangle and 0 otherwise.

3) end[i][j].second is 1 if s[i][j] is joined with upper-# and 2 if left-# and 0 if s[i][j] is not used.

```
    int dp[n][n];
    pair<int, int> end[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            // w is the answer for (i x j) without using s[i][j]
            w = (i - 1 >= 0 ? dp[i - 1][j] : 0) + (j - 1 >= 0 ? dp[i][j - 1] : 0) - (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0 ? dp[i - 1][j - 1] : 0);
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0 && end[i - 1][j].first == 1 && end[i - 1][j].second == 2 && end[i][j - 1].first == 1 && end[i][j - 1].second == 1) w--; 
            x = y = 0;
            if (s[i][j] == '#') {
                if (i > 0) {
                    // using the upper # if present
                    if (s[i - 1][j] == '#') x = 1 + (i - 2 >= 0 ? dp[i - 2][j] : 0) + (j - 1 >= 0 ? dp[i][j - 1] : 0) - (i - 2 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0 ? dp[i - 2][j - 1] : 0);
                    if (i - 2 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0 && end[i - 1][j - 1].first == 1 && end[i - 1][j - 1].second == 1 && end[i - 2][j].first == 1 && end[i - 2][j].second == 2) x--;
                    if (x <= w) x = 0;
                }
                if (j > 0) {
                    //using the left # if present
                    if (s[i][j - 1] == '#') y = 1 + (i - 1 >= 0 ? dp[i - 1][j] : 0) + (j - 2 >= 0 ? dp[i][j - 2] : 0) - (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 2 >= 0 ? dp[i - 1][j - 2] : 0);
                    if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 2 >= 0 && end[i - 1][j - 1].first == 1 && end[i - 1][j - 1].second == 2 && end[i][j - 2].first == 1 && end[i][j - 2].second == 1) y--;
                    if (y <= w) y = 0;
                }   
            }

            // choosing the maximum of the three and accordingly assigning end[i][j]
            if (w >= x && w >= y) {
                dp[i][j] = w;
                end[i][j] = make_pair(0, 0);
            } else if (x > w && x > y) {
                dp[i][j] = x;
                end[i][j] = make_pair(1, 1);
            } else {
                dp[i][j] = y;
                end[i][j] = make_pair(1, 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look into self documenting code.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve !

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not about dynamic programming. It's about the maximum matching. Let's paint the grid with black and white colors(like a chess board). Now we have a bipartite graph(black cells are in the first part and white cells are in the second one). We should add edges between adjacent cells if both of them contain oil. The answer is the size of the maximum matching in this graph.